# CouchDB 2.1.1 compact views by shard

Tags: couchdb

### Issue

Compacting views across my cluster doesn't seem to use the IOQ properly, resulting in IO timeouts and very high load on my servers. I'm trying to mitigate this by compacting on a per-shard basis, rather than across the whole cluster at once.

### Compacting the DB by shard

I can compact each **database** at the shard level, by using the node-local port (5986):

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5986/shards%2F00000000-1fffffff%2Fexample.1511755818/_compact`

### Can I compact each view by shard?

I've tried to do a compact on each view by shard (ie)

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5986/shards%2F00000000-1fffffff%2Fexample.1511755818/viewname/_compact`

But I get a "not found" error

**Is it possible to compact each view by shard in CouchDB 2.1?**

Appreciate the help. I'm writing a node.js util to do this and will release once I can do the view part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this up, the URL for compacting a view is as follows:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5986/shards%2F00000000-1fffffff%2Fexample.1511755818/_compact/<viewname>
```

I had the last two URL paths the wrong way around